# Stack dimensions of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have a numpy array of shape (2500, 16, 32, 24), and I want to make it into a ( something, 24) array, but I don't want numpy to shuffle my values. The 32 x 24 dimension at the end represent images and I want the corresponding elements to be consistent. Any ideas?

EDIT: Ok , I wasn't clear enough. (something, 24) = (1280000, 24).

Comment: What do you mean by `something, 24`?

Comment: So you look for a 40000x32x24 array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `arr.reshape(-1,arr.shape[-1])` or if you know it will be 24 `arr.reshape(-1,24)`